# How to express static (immutable) state of React component instance?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

What is best (most performant & best practice) way to express **static (immutable) state of component** using functional React api?

For real world use case, imagine that we need to generate unique static identifier (for html `id`) for each of react component instance.

1) One way might be using internal component state (`useState`)

```
let incrementId = 1;

const Slider = () => {
  const [id] = useState(`slider_${incrementId++}`); // THIS LINE
  return <div id={id}>...</div>
}
```

2) Or alternatively using memoizing (`useMemo`)

```
let incrementId = 1;

const Slider = () => {
  const id = useMemo(() => `slider_${incrementId++}`, []);  // THIS LINE
  return <div id={id}>...</div>
}
```

3) Maybe there is third way.

I would naturally use `1) useState` as it does signalize that we are talking about component state, but just recently saw that `useMemo` was used for this same reason.

To expand initial question a bit, can be both methods here used to safely express this scenarios, or is one of those better (faster, more clear) ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a performance consideration here, as the code is run only once in both cases.

I would extract this to it's own hook and use like this:

```
let incrementId = 1;
const useSliderId = () => useMemo(() => `slider_${incrementId++}`, []);
```

Usage:

```
const Slider = () => {
    const id = useSliderId()
    ...
}
```